# C++ Piped data prints out in blocks

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, cout

I'm trying to write a program which takes the `stdout` of another program splits it into lines and prints it.

This other program constantly outputs data(about 800 characters per second) non-stop.

I've forked it and used dup2 to send its `stdout` to a pipe to the parent process.

The problem is that the parent process reads the data but it can only print it out in blocks of about 150 lines every 6ish seconds.

So it prints data, then nothing for 6 seconds, then more data, then nothing....over and over

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int pipe1[2];
    char readbuf[5];
    string line = ">>";

    if (pipe(pipe1) != 0){                  //Setting up the pipe
        cerr << "Pipe failed\n"; exit(1);
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();                     //Setting up the fork

    if (pid < 0){
        cerr << "Fork failed\n" ;exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0){
                                            //Child Process
        dup2(pipe1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);      //dup2()ing stdout to pipe 
        close(pipe1[1]);                    //closing other pipe connections
        close(pipe1[0]);

        execl("program_folder/program", "program_folder/program", NULL); //running the program
    }
    else{
                                //Parent
        close(pipe1[1]);        //closing write end of pipe

        for (;;){

                do{
                    if (read(pipe1[0], readbuf, 1) < 0){
                        cout << "read error"<<endl;
                        return 1;
                    }                           //Reads 1 character at a time,
                    line.push_back(readbuf[0]); //pushing them onto a string,    
                }while(readbuf[0] != '\n');     //until the new line character is reached

                cout<< line;                    //Prints the line of data
                line= ">>";
        }
        close(pipe1[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this: (yaw, pitch, roll values)

```
>>ypr    63.71  -68.52   19.24
>>ypr    63.75  -68.52   19.24
>>ypr    63.78  -68.52   19.24
>>ypr    63.81  -68.52   19.24
>>ypr    63.85  -68.52   19.24
>>ypr    63.89  -68.52   19.23
>>ypr    63.93  -68.52   19.24
>>ypr    63.97  -68.52   19.24
>>ypr    64.00  -68.52   19.24
```

In the future I want to send these through a socket to another computer and plot them in real time, with something like gnuplot. I know it would be easier with python but I just wanted to try it with C.

I've tried using std::endl; and std::cout.flush(); but no luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". Distinguish C and C++. Refine your question to only one language.

Comment: Does `program_folder/program` print non-stop every line without pausing? A pipe has a limit capacity (see [man 7 pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) and when the buffer is full, `write` will block until the reading side read enough bytes, perhaps you could set a greater capacity with `fcntl`.

Comment: Yeah. program prints out about 5-10 lines a second continuously. Its data from an acellorometers/gyros. Maybe the pipe is filling but the program should be able to read and print it faster the 5-10 lines a second, right?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't had a case where I need to read output fast through a pipe, I would have to test it.

Comment: I created an example program that outputs the line you with random sleeps of 100 - 200 ms, so it prints between 5 and 10 lines every second: https://pastebin.com/06s90CND I use your code (obliviously changing the `execl` line) and when I run your program, it prints as fast as the forked program outputs, the lag is minimal. So I think you probably have the problem at an other part of your code that you are not showing.

Comment: okay, thanks! I tried timing it again it might be a bit faster then 10 lines, hard to tell. I didnt write the program, its a demo code and drivers for an MPU6050 on a ras pi. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=210497#p210497. I'm fairly sure if there is anything wrong it is probably on my end. You're probably right about the pipe running out of space. ill have to slow it down and test it. Thanks!

Comment: You don't flush your output, so it just accumulates data until the buffer is full. Try flushing the output explicitly `cout << line << std::flush;`. Even if it's not enough to fix your issue, you have to do it if you want output to appear as it comes.

Comment: @NickyC, as the question shows a `using namespace std;`, we can assume the language is C++, and incorrectly tagged as C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using pipes, there's no more line per line output in the data stream.  This is a general UNIX issue.  stdout checks if the output stream is a tty (by a call to `isatty(3)`), so it flushes output at each `\n` found in the output, or when `BUFSIZ` character fill up the buffer.  As you have `pipe(2)`d in your program, there's no more line buffering, so buffer is flushed at block chunks.  You can force when you want the flushes, by inserting a call to `fflush(stdout);` in the proper places (C language).  Or as have been pointed to in the comments (thanks @spectras) with the following line (for C++ only):

```
cout <<  "your line here" << std::flush;
```

(You must edit the pipe writer, as you cannot control how the writer buffer operates from the reader process.)

Comment: Cheers, putting an `fflush(stdout);` in the writing program(the program executed with `execl();`)works. Is there no way of reading the output continuously from the parent process (if you weren't able to access the source code and edit the writing program)?